# How to convert object to array to get the data?

Tags: php, wordpress

My array coming like this

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 578 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2011-01-18 07:23:17 [post_date_gmt] => 2011-01-18 07:23:17 [post_content] => Home WordPress is web software you can use to create a beautiful website or blog. We like to say that WordPress is both free and priceless at the same time. The core software is built by hundreds of community volunteers, and when you’re ready for more there are thousands of plugins and themes available to transform your site into almost anything you can imagine. Over 25 million people have chosen WordPress to power the place on the web they call “home” — we’d love you to join the family [post_title] => second post [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open
```

when i write like this

```
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$arrDt = (array) $myposts;
print_r($arrDt);
```

but my problem is how can i get the values inside that object array.

please help.
Thnx 
print_r($arrDt);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just normal object access:

```
$obj = $arrDt[0];
echo $obj->ID;
echo $obj->post_author;
// etc.
```

But it depends on what you want to do. I suggest to have a look at the [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) examples. They use `setup_postdata` to load the post content in the current context. If you want to display the post, this is probably the cleaner solution.

Comment: @user if an answer solves your question, you are encouraged to accept it by ticking the green checkmark outline next to it. If there is multiple answers, tick the one that was most helpful to you and consider upvoting any other answers.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple:

You have an Array `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID]`

This array have one KEY, that can be identified by the "[0]" (but more keys may exist))
Accessing the key:

```
foreach ( $arrDt as $value ): //Look, whe are inside the first key. (currently is '0').
   echo $value->ID;
   echo $value->post_author;
endforeach;
```

Or, if you want to convert object to array ( like $value['ID'], for example ), you just needs this:

```
    function objectToArray($obj)
    {
         if (is_object($obj)):
             $object = get_object_vars($obj); 
         endif;

         return array_map('objectToArray', $object); // return the object, converted in array.
    }

$objArray = objectToArray($arrDt);
print_r($objArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was:

```
foreach ($returnedObject as $row) {
    $sub_array = '';
    $sub_array['ID'] = $row->data->ID;
    $sub_array['user_login'] = $row->data->user_login;
    $sub_array['display_name'] = $row->data->display_name;
    $sub_array['user_email'] = $row->data->user_email;
    $sub_array['user_registered'] = $row->data->user_registered;
    $main_array[] = $sub_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **wp_get_recent_posts()** instead of **get_posts()**. The **wp_get_recent_posts()** function returns a normal array instead of object array, then by using foreach loop you can access any value of an array.